# Custom help command

Tags: discord.py

Hi I’m trying to code a simple discord bot using discord.py, and one of the things I want my bot to do is send a nice custom embed when a user uses the !help command. So far I know that this simple code, which some people provided in other questions on stackoverflow about custom help commands:

```py
class help(commands.MinimalHelpCommand):
  async def send_pages(self):
    destination = self.get_destination()
    e = discord.Embed(title="Help:", description="description", colour=discord.Colour.blurple(), timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    await destination.send(embed=e)

client.help_command = help()
```

works, but the thing is when someone wants to use !help on a specific command or category, the bot will only send the send_pages command. I tried modifying the code and added

```py
  async def send_page_command(self, *, command):
    destination = self.get_destination
    command_e = discord.Embed(title="Dogluva:robot's Help:", description=f"{command.description}", colour=discord.Colour.blurple(), timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    await destination.send(embed=command_e)
```

But this doesn’t help. Anyone know what I’m doing wrong here? I’ve set the description for all the commands I wrote in my cogs using `commands.command(description=“description")` but I don’t know how to make a custom help command access those descriptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
@client.command()
async def help(ctx, *, command=None):
  if command == None:
    e = discord.Embed(title="Dogluva:robot:'s Help:", description=“Custom Description", colour=discord.Colour.blurple(), timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
  elif command == “{command}":
    e = discord.Embed(title="Dogluva:robot:'s Help:", description=“Command Description", colour=discord.Colour.blurple(), timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow())

  await ctx.send(embed=e)
```

I just created different cases for each command

Answer (score 1):

First, remember to **delete the default help command** (discord automatically has help command), so you need to delete it first:

```py
client.remove_command('help') # before your own "help" command

# or

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="<your prefix>", help_command=None) # when you create client
```

---

**Basic help command:**

```py
@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Help", description="Write your own description here", colour=discord.Color.blue())

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

But you can make it even better. Read more about Embeds in the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.Embed) and check this template:
[image]

Comment: OK thanks, so I just create cases where the user asks for a specific command and the bot sends a different embed, right? Or is there an easier way so that the code can loop through all the commands and find the one that the user asked for, then edit an embed (using the description of the command)

Comment: @dogluva check out the commands framework [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

instead of `send_page_command(self, *, command):` you can try using `send_command_help(self, command):`

https://gist.github.com/InterStella0/b78488fb28cadf279dfd3164b9f0cf96